# how to use my pc as internet server so that my local websites are available online

Tags: iis-7.5

I need advice: I want my local hosted websites to be available in the public internet. I do not want to turn off firewalls. If I buy a domain name can I use it locally?How?
I want to use my pc as staging server for testing  before deploying to production server

Answer (score 0):

Check out these sites, which give a basic introductory explanation of what you need to do to get it working:

http://www.wikihow.com/Host-Your-Own-Website-for-Free
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Web-Host-in-Your-Home

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out this link for how to install Apache, which you'll most likely want to use:

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-Apache-Web-Server-on-a-Windows-PC

This site helped me sort out my dynamic IP address problems:

http://www.dslwebserver.com/main/fr_index.html?/main/diagram-multiport-router.html

Comment: I am on windows 8 using iis

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup port redirection on your router to you computer IP then simply set the incoming port of IIS to the port you just created on the router. Then to call your IIS it will be as simple as your `http:\\[WAN IP]:[PORT]\`